# Correr proyecto de GitHub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, github

Saludo a todos.
Acabo de descargar un proytecto Web por GitHub, pero a la hora de correrlo desde mi ordenador me arroja el siguiente error y no carga el localhost en mi navegador. Es de C# Asp .net Core

"System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)'"

El error proviene de los metodos de este modelo

namespace OnSale.Web.Helpers
{
public class BlobHelper : IBlobHelper
{
private readonly CloudBlobClient _blobClient;

```
    public BlobHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        string keys = configuration["Blob:ConnectionString"];
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(keys);
        _blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    }

    public async Task<Guid> UploadBlobAsync(byte[] file, string containerName)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, containerName);
    }

    public async Task<Guid> UploadBlobAsync(IFormFile file, string containerName)
    {
        Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, containerName);
    }

    public async Task<Guid> UploadBlobAsync(string image, string containerName)
    {
        Stream stream = File.OpenRead(image);
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, containerName);
    }

    public async Task<Guid> UploadBlobAsync(Stream stream, string containerName)
    {
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, containerName);
    }

    private async Task<Guid> UploadStreamAsync(Stream stream, string containerName)
    {
        Guid name = Guid.NewGuid();
        CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{name}");
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        return name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: podrias mirar [ask]. Sin ver el codigo, sin saber cuando pasa eso, sin saber como intentaste correrlo, es imposible decirte absolutamente nada...

Comment: Se necesita conocer el contexto en que se produce el error y ademas conocer el punto exacto donde salta la excepción. La programación es rica, creativa. Se puede lograr que un codigo devuelva los mismos resultados y si se le pidió a muchos porgramadores, habra tantos códigos validos, diferentes, como programadores y todos devolveran el mismo resultado. Por tanto por muy inteligente que alguien sea, nunca podra descifrar donde se produce el error de tu codigo si no lo muestras. Mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y presenta lo que intentaste.

Comment: @EduardoReyes eso dice el error Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
    [Código externo]
    OnSale.Web.Helpers.BlobHelper.UploadStreamAsync(System.IO.Stream, string) en BlobHelper.cs
    [Código externo]

Comment: OnSale.Web.Helpers.BlobHelper.UploadBlobAsync(System.IO.Stream, string) en BlobHelper.cs
    [Código externo]
    OnSale.Web.Data.SeedDb.CheckUserAsync(string, string, OnSale.Common.Enums.UserType) en SeedDb.cs
    [Código externo]
    OnSale.Web.Data.SeedDb.CheckAdminsAsync() en SeedDb.cs
    [Código externo]
    OnSale.Web.Data.SeedDb.CheckUsersAsync() en SeedDb.cs
    ...
    [Pila de llamadas truncada] @EduardoReyes

Comment: Ya hiciste el `dotnet restore` ? También ya cambiaste hacia donde apunta el blob?

Comment: @JaimeJonathanOrtizVelazco ese comando lo corro en la consola del administrador de paquetes?

Comment: @joseramirez si el dotnet restore corres en la consola desde la carpeta de la aplicación. Pero otra consulta? este código se ejecuta o se llama desde un controlador? porque el error que devuelve es que la cabecera de Autorización esta mal construida

Comment: @joseramirez si, lo corres desde ahi